# QGraphicsPathItem hoverEvents - suppress hover on area formed by the path

Tags: qt, pyqt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, mousehover

https://www.dropbox.com/s/phven3rriv36893/graphicsview-pathitem.png?dl=0
I wonder if there's a way to make my QGraphicsPathItem respond to mouseHoverEvents to the actual curve instead of the whole orange area as seen in the docs.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m8w34nitp34sgf/pipes.png?dl=0
In my application I'm not seeing the area that actually forms the path and therefor I only want a hoverEnterEvent when the bezier curve is hovered (and a hoverLeaveEvent when the bezier is left of, course).

Is that possible to achieve with QGraphicsPathItem or is that a completely wrong approach? If yes, how? If not, what QGraphics object can be considered as a replacement?

If code is really needed, let me know.

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reimplement `QGraphicsItem.shape` to return a more accurate representation of your curve.  The default implementation gives you the bounding box as you've discovered.

Answer (score 5):

Tim Wakeham's answer is totally correct: you need to re-implement `shape()` to provide a more detailed shape for your path item.   However, his answer is not totally useful, since it's not trivial to implement a good `shape()` method returning the right `QPainterPath`.

It's even more confusing because in this case, the `QGraphicsPathItem` can already provide a `QPainterPath` from its `path()` method.  Unfortunately that is generally not the right value to return from the `shape()` method since it draws the item rather than delimits its outside.

Fortunately, since this is a fairly standard requirement, there is a built-in class to transform the path into an outline that can be used for the shape: `QPainterPathStroker`.

Here's some code I use to do that:

```
    qp = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
    qp.setWidth(MARGIN)
    qp.setCapStyle(QtCore.Qt.SquareCap)
    shape = qp.createStroke(self.path())
```