# Selecting QGraphicsPathItem incorrect

Tags: pyside, qgraphicsitem

Why does there appear to be a selection issue regarding QGraphicsPAthItem's that are bezier paths? In the image below you can see my cursor is no where close to the line but it shows as being in a hover state turn the line White.

The more curvy the line, the more inaccurate the hover/selecting is. How can i fix this? The red X indicates the location of my cursor.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435391/3156300

```
qp = QPainterPathStroker()
qp.setWidth(12)
qp.setCapStyle(Qt.SquareCap)
return qp.createStroke(self.path())
```